# How to put the result of a Boolean test into a variable?

Tags: bash

There is something I do not understand regarding Bash variable assignment. I want to create a predicate (so, a variable whose value is either `true` or `false`) `foo` that I could use later in my script and that would be equal to the result of a certain Boolean operation. An ideal code would be like the following, which does not work:

```
var=1
foo=[[ $var = 2 ]] # wishing foo to be equal to the result of the test "$var = 2"
bash: 1 : command not found
foo=test $var = 2
bash: 1 : command not found
```

In other words, I wonder if there is a shorter way other than:

```
f(){
  if [[ $var = 2 ]]; then echo true
  else echo false
  fi
}
foo=$(f)
```

that could give the same final value to foo.  What are your thoughts about this? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you just need to know if it is running.

Comment: @BobMonk I use it multiple times after this so I would like to store it... The problem does not come from `systemctl`, afaik.

Comment: You need to read/learn about bash syntax, It does not work like that. Try https://shellcheck.net to verify your script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In bash, how to store a return value in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013481/in-bash-how-to-store-a-return-value-in-a-variable)

Comment: This question is changing everytime...

Comment: Sorry for changing the question, I am trying to make as minimal as I can...

Comment: The `[[` is a command which is like the `test` command but with more feature, so to put your assignment in a way you can understand is   `foo=test $var = 1`

Comment: The only difference is that the `[[` needs a closing `]]` , but before someone tells me that what `[[` really is check the output of `type [[`

Comment: a=[] will create an empty array

Answer (score 0):

To store permanetly a variable you must use db or file, instead if you want to store it only for this session check it:"[What are sessions? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work)". 
if you want to store it on a file check:it:[Saving php output in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870576/saving-php-output-in-a-file/5870612)"

Answer (score 0):

`Echo "is active" >> server log.txt`

Or

Echo the result of systemctl

`> This will always make a new file`

`>> Will append to a file or create if not there`

You could do with maybe recording the time to the file also.

Additionally

`==` I believe needed to check if numeric is true
`-eq` I believe if a string

```
echo "Run script"

    read -r approveAction

     approved=$(echo "$approveAction" | awk '{print tolower($1)}' | sed "s/[^[:alpha:]^[:digit:]]//g")

     if [ $approved == "y" ] ;

     then

      when=date
         echo "user agreement "$when>> userlog.log
       ./script.sh


     fi
```

Here's an example from a script asking for users permission to run a script

FROM YOUR CHANGE OF QUESTION

```
var=1

if [[ $var == 1 ]]; then 
    echo "true" 
else 
    echo "false"
fi
```

This works

Comment: I do not want to store it into a logfile or anything... And I believe the `==` operator is not the recommended syntax for an equality test (although also supported). `-eq` does not work either.

Comment: If using single = then single [ are needed, -eq is for integer

Comment: I believe that equation doesn't actually result in anything. a equal array of 1 , = and 1